# Plotting a simple plane in 3D

Tags: r, plot, regression, rgl, plot3d

I am trying to plot a plane in a 3D environment in the context of a multivariate regression. I have a linear regression polynomial in the form of f(x)=beta_1 + beta_2*x_1 + beta_3 * x_3.

Obviously this formula describes a plane in R^3. I would like to plot this, but I fail to see how to do this efficiently. Obviously, what I need to do is to create a sort of grid on which I compute the values of my regression polynomial.

So far, this is what I have:

```
beta <- c(1, 1, 1) #  Placeholder. This is the output of my regression analysis
p <- function(k) { t(beta) %*% k }

n <- 20
m <- 50

x <- seq(from=5, to=13, length.out=n)
z <- seq(from=20, to=50, length.out=m)
M <- mesh(x, z)
```

Now as far as I understand it, whether I'm using plot3D or rgl, I need to compute the value of `p` on these grid elements and store it in a matrix of dimension `m * n`. Obviously, in other languages I would just iterate over both matrices and fill the values in `y` by hand, but this seems very ugly and unfitting for R to me. So after some research, I stumbled upon the function `mapply`, which applies a function over two matrices. Note that the input to `p` requires a 1 to be appended to the argument before the call.

```
mapply(function (x1, x2) { p(c(1, x1, x2)) }, M$x, M$y)
```

But the output for this is very, very, very ugly and far from what I expected. Could someone help me out? It surprises me that plotting a plane in 3D seems to be so difficult, because after all, all that we need to uniquely determine a plane are three points in space. And yet all frameworks require me to use fairly complicated function calls?

I am sorry if the solution to my issue is trivial. I've checked out quite a few similar threads, but I still can't quite wrap my head around what I need to do as the issue at hand should be so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `rgl` it's much simpler:  just use `planes3d`.  That function defines planes using the parameterization `a x + b y + c z + d = 0`, so if we assume `x1`, `f(x)` and `x3` in your notation are `x`, `y` and `z` in `rgl` notation, you would plot the plane using

```
planes3d(beta2, -1, beta3, beta1)
```

One complication is that planes are infinite, so you have to specify which part you want to plot in some other way.  The usual way is to use `plot3d()` to set up a coordinate system, e.g.

```
plot3d(x1, y, x3, xlab = "x_1", ylab = "f(x)", zlab = "x_3")
```

Comment: Edit: I figured it out, was much easier than what I expected. Thanks a lot!